# convert string number expressions to numbers

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with string expressions like {"1 / 2", "0.5"}. How can I convert such strings to actual numbers? I know there is `destring` but that only converts  "number strings" to numbers; the "number expressions" are returned as missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Note that `real()` doesn't help here. Here is a crude solution:

```
clear 
input str6 myproblem 
"1 / 2"
"0.5"
"ln(3)" 
end 

gen onesolution = .
quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
    replace onesolution = `= myproblem[`i']' in `i'
} 

list 

     +---------------------+
     | myprob~m   onesol~n |
     |---------------------|
  1. |    1 / 2         .5 |
  2. |      0.5         .5 |
  3. |    ln(3)   1.098612 |
     +---------------------+
```

Comment: That works, but I remember reading somewhere some years ago (circa version 11) that iterating observation by observation is slow in Stata. Is that still the case in the newest versions?

Comment: That's one reason why I call it crude. Looping over observations is always the last resort.